# Python get mnc and country code of mobile/phone number

Tags: python, python-2.7

How i will get MNC and Country code separated from a international mobile/phone number

i've used below libraries :

1. [Python Phone numbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers)
2. [phone-iso3166](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phone-iso3166)

**// i need something like**

```
number = validate("+919746XXXX")

number.mnc()
9746

number.country_code()
91
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the country code of a phone number using the [phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) library, try:

```
>>> import phonenumbers
>>> x = phonenumbers.parse("+442083661177", None)
>>> x.country_code
44
```

As for the mobile network code, phone numbers can move between the different operators so you can't detect mnc by the phone number only.