# Detect country code from phone number | Python

Tags: python

I am building a whatsapp bot and I need to message any unsaved number, so I am using whatsapp api "https://wa.me/phonenumber", but the phone number must include the country code, so is there any way that I can detect this code from the number itself? I mean that the phone doesn't include the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python get mnc and country code of mobile/phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800218/python-get-mnc-and-country-code-of-mobile-phone-number)

Comment: It doesn't, I need to get the code without having the code itself in the phone. I am asking if there is a way around. but thanks anyway @buran

Comment: So you're asking for the difference between the german number 04012345678 and the french number 04012345678?

Comment: so THERE are similar numbers but the difference is the code right ?

Comment: so there is no way

Comment: The country code IS the difference. That's what it's for.

Comment: The link I reference points to a python library that parse a phone number you provide. there is no need to have the code in the phone. Note how good is the library in parsing the phone number is another matter